# Flask: cannot unpack non-iterable int object in Python list

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterable

I have a list like so:

```
my_list = []
check_values = [1, 2, 5]

str_input = "5"

my_list.append(int(str_input))
```

Then I try to create a set to test some stuff:

```
testing = list(set(v for k, v in my_list if int(k) in check_values))
```

I get the following error on the line above:

```
Flask: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: So the first element of `my_list` is an int (5) that is non-iterable and therefore cannot be unpacked. When you write `k, v` Python expects that each element of the list is an iterable (tuple, list) with two elements

Answer (score 2):

The "unpacking" is happening in your generator expression when Python tries to "unpack" each value of `my_list` into the two variables `k` and `v`.

It looks like maybe you adapted this from code that was iterating over a `dict.items()` instead of a plain list of integers.

Fix with:

`testing = list(set(v for v in my_list if int(v) in check_values))`

Or use a set union:

`testing = list(set(my_list) | check_values)`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of the usage of the `k` variable in your for structure - what is it trying to achieve?

However, using `k, v` in a for is usually applicable to dictionaries, not lists. (unless I'm missing something)

Just update your code to

```
testing = list(set(v for v in my_list if int(v) in check_values))
```

Comment: Ah yes I have another set that is a dictionary and copied the code from there. That makes sense. I've only been learning python for 2 weeks.

Comment: Pay attention to the difference between the sets and dictionaries, because it's quite important. Dictionaries keys are actually just a set, since they are unique and immutable.